# How to stop changing text inside textbox with same ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have more forms like this:

```
<form ng-submit="addReply(x)" class="dd animated slideInDown" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <text-angular ng-model="form.reply"></text-angular>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Send" />
                </div>
</form>
```

Have problem with text area because of `ng-model="form.reply"` when I change some textarea all other text areas are automatically changed... How to prevent it?

Here is example:
http://jsfiddle.net/oLv61qtr/

I just need change one not both...

Comment: Where is your other `text-area`'s?

Comment: provide a jsfiddle link to replicate your problem

Comment: `<text-angular ng-model="form.reply"></text-angular>`

Comment: If these forms all use the same model (model.reply) then changing it in one will always change it in others, at the end of the day it is the same variable! Probably using different model variables to store text in each form is the best idea.

Comment: added fiddle, please chack it.

Comment: Like I said, you won't be able to do it, forget about trying, use different models.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't do it.
If you have multiple text fields using the same model variable, they will always display the same value. At the end of the day it is the same variable, so how can it have different values in different places?
Use different model variable on different forms if you need. That seems like the best solution.

Comment: Is there any other way to take value of textarea from current submited form?